# UIDatePicker "copyWithZone" Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

This is the following code for scheduling an alarm, and I am receiving the following error. It had been working perfectly until I tried to compare the current date to the picker:

```
[self.eventText resignFirstResponder];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

//Get the current date
NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

//Unable to set notification for same day
[datePicker setMinimumDate:[NSDate date]];

//Break the date up into components
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components: (NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:pickerDate];
NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components: (NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:pickerDate];

// Schedule the notification
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = datePicker;
localNotification.alertBody = self.eventText.text;
localNotification.alertAction = @"Show me the item";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Object 1", @"Key 1", @"Object 2", @"Key 2", nil];
localNotification.userInfo = infoDict;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

// Request to reload table view data
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

eventText.text = nil;

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Receiving the following error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception `NSInvalidArgumentException`, reason: `-[UIDatePicker copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ba853f0`. I am terrible at debugging and have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having lies in this line, I believe

```
localNotification.fireDate = datePicker;
```

You didn't provide the code above that defines "datePicker", but my guess is that you meant to type "pickerDate" and not "datePicker", which doesn't conform to the NSCopying protocol (and isn't an NSDate anyway), which is why the error is thrown.

Comment: Thank you for such a fast response, great answer.